# Angular ng-select how to prevent the previous selected item

Tags: angular

I have a component using ng-select. I found something similar on stackblitz. [Link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-clear-on-backspace).
Every time I enter a value to search for in ng-select and then remove it with a backspace it shows me the last selected item. How can I cancel displaying it?
[image]

Comment: You need to enter another Backspace to remove model data.

Comment: @RaselAhmed the essence of my question is to get rid of the double backspace.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably setting the `placeholder` value on successful selection of the `ng-select`. Please check the `change` event.

Comment: could you tell more, please?